# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. firebase rt db

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs

As soon as I call an asynchronous function of the firebase database, the test does not exit correctly.

**The errors**

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the
 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

and

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubles
hoot this issue.
```

- `--detectOpenHandles` show nothing.
- `done()` of Jest does nothing
- I do not want to increase Jest timeout

**firebase.spec.js**

```
const firebase = require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing')

describe('firebase', () => {

  it('should work', async () => {
    const admin = firebase.initializeAdminApp({
      projectId: 'lol',
      databaseName: 'lol'
    })

    const db = admin.database()

    // Commenting the following line make the error disappear
    await db.ref('ok').set('ko')

    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })

})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "firebase-test-js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest src"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/functions/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^1.1.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.2.2"
  }
}
```

Edit : completely forgot to add error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code fix**

```
afterEach(async () => {
  await Promise.all(admin.apps.map(app => app?.delete()))
  return Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()))
})
```

After searching for 1 week on every king of support possible, I stumbled on [This awesome video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rRr9GnynR0).

At **10:42**, I saw my answer.

The famous teardown.

**Make sure to delete both apps coming from firebase-admin and @firebase/rules-unit-testing**

I went over their documentation a billion times about test setup and their official video [Awesome but incomplete tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDulvfBpzZE) see **27:39**, I don't know how they and I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue on an expo (react-native) environment.

**Fix:**

1. Ensure you wait on all promises related to cleanup
   e.g.

```js
afterEach(async () => {
    await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()))
})
```

2. Ensure you have the most recent version of jest

```
npx jest -v
```

I found myself having this issue on jest version `25.5.4`, but not on `26.6.3`

**Extra:**

Expo may download its own (slightly older) version of jest.

If `npm install --save-dev jest` (or `yarn add -D jest`) doesn't update the jest version make sure to remove all `node_modules` caches first. (especially `node_modules/.bin/jest` if present)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! For me, the problem was in the jest version as well